# Javafx Webview Exception

Tags: java, webview, javafx-2

I am trying to load a page into webview. When I try to load https://www.google.com/ then it doesn't complain, but
when I try to load other sites it throws below exception:

> Jan 16, 2016 4:14:20 PM com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader doRun
>   WARNING: Unexpected error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol
>   = https host = null   at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:176)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1099)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>     at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.close(URLLoader.java:591)   at
>   com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.doRun(URLLoader.java:173)    at
>   com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$run$91(URLLoader.java:128)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.run(URLLoader.java:127)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Jan 16, 2016 4:14:20 PM com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader doRun
>   WARNING: Unexpected error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol
>   = https host = null   at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:176)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1099)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:999)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>     at com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.close(URLLoader.java:591)   at
>   com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.doRun(URLLoader.java:173)    at
>   com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.lambda$run$91(URLLoader.java:128)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   com.sun.webkit.network.URLLoader.run(URLLoader.java:127)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I have tried setting proxies but I think I am doing it wrong.
Any Suggestions?

Comment: The error says the host is null.  What is the url you are loading?  My guess is you are determining the host from some variable which is null, but it is just a guess.  You might wish to provide an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: the url I am accessing is https://www.24option.com/,
and I am passing it directly to webEngine.load()